# Flask and Heroku - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'

Tags: heroku, flask

I'm trying to deploy a Flask app to Heroku. After deploying, application crashes and I get an error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'.

Project structure:

```
.
├── ./espncricinfo
│      ├── ./exceptions.py
│      ├── ./__init__.py
│      ├── ./match.py
│      ├── ./player.py
│      ├── ./summary.py
│
├── ./pycricbuzz 
│      ├──./cricbuzz.py
│      ├──./ __init__.py
├── ./pycricket
│      ├── ./cricket.py
│      ├──./ __init__.py
├── ./static
│      ├── ./bblpics
│      ├── ./fonts
│      ├── ./images
│      ├── ./favascripts
│      ├── ./stylesheets
├── ./templates    
│      ├── ./index.html
│      ├── ./base.html
│      ├── ./app.html
│      ├── ./Smmary.html
│      ├── ./Scorecard.html
│      ├── ./News.html
├── ./__init__.py
│
├── ./Procfile
│
├── ./requirements.txt
│
├── ./runtime.txt
│
├── ./bbl.py
│    
└── ./score.py
```

I'm doing in virtualenv
I pip installed these dependices 
pip install Flask
pip install requests
pip install pytz
pip install praw
pip install beautifulsoup4
pip install google-api-python-client
pip install python-dateutil
pip install python-espncricinfo
pip install pandas
pip install gunicorn

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
echo web: gunicorn app:app > Procfile
echo python-3.6.4 >runtime.txt

git init
heroku login
heroku create the-wall-cricket-scores
git add .
git commit -m "fdf"
git push heroku master
heroku open
```

This is my main **init**.py

```
 app = Flask(__name__)



    if __name__=="__main__":
        app.run(debug=True)
```

Procfile web: gunicorn app:app
    runtime.txt python-3.6.4

Requirements.txt-

```
beautifulsoup4==4.6.0
bs4==0.0.1
certifi==2018.1.18
chardet==3.0.4
click==6.7
dateparser==0.7.0
Flask==0.12.2
google-api-python-client==1.6.5
gunicorn==19.7.1
httplib2==0.10.3
idna==2.6
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.10
MarkupSafe==1.0
numpy==1.14.0
oauth2client==4.1.2
pandas==0.22.0
praw==5.3.0
prawcore==0.13.0
pyasn1==0.4.2
pyasn1-modules==0.2.1
python-dateutil==2.6.1
python-espncricinfo==0.3.1
pytz==2018.3
regex==2018.2.8
requests==2.18.4
rsa==3.4.2
six==1.11.0
tzlocal==1.5.1
update-checker==0.16
uritemplate==3.0.0
urllib3==1.22
Werkzeug==0.14.1
```

I get an error as follow : 
Error full details:

```
2018-02-20T06:52:40.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2018-02-20T06:54:00.350992+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn app:app`
2018-02-20T06:54:01.598198+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn app:app`
2018-02-20T06:54:03.409972+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-02-20 06:54:03 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
2018-02-20T06:54:03.413413+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-02-20 06:54:03 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:34331 (4)
2018-02-20T06:54:03.413643+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-02-20 06:54:03 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2018-02-20T06:54:03.420766+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-02-20 06:54:03 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
2018-02-20T06:54:03.431463+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-02-20 06:54:03 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2018-02-20T06:54:03.431467+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-02-20T06:54:03.431469+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 578, in spawn_worker
2018-02-20T06:54:03.431471+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2018-02-20T06:54:03.431473+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
2018-02-20T06:54:03.431474+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.load_wsgi()
2018-02-20T06:54:03.431476+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 135, in load_wsgi
2018-02-20T06:54:03.431478+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2018-02-20T06:54:03.431480+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2018-02-20T06:54:03.431482+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2018-02-20T06:54:03.431483+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
2018-02-20T06:54:03.431485+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2018-02-20T06:54:03.431487+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
2018-02-20T06:54:03.431489+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2018-02-20T06:54:03.431490+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 352, in import_app
2018-02-20T06:54:03.431492+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2018-02-20T06:54:03.431534+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
2018-02-20T06:54:03.431765+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-02-20 06:54:03 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
2018-02-20T06:54:03.473017+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-02-20 06:54:03 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2018-02-20T06:54:03.484252+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-02-20 06:54:03 +0000] [9] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2018-02-20T06:54:03.484255+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-02-20T06:54:03.484257+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 578, in spawn_worker
2018-02-20T06:54:03.484258+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2018-02-20T06:54:03.484260+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
2018-02-20T06:54:03.484262+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.load_wsgi()
2018-02-20T06:54:03.484263+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 135, in load_wsgi
2018-02-20T06:54:03.484265+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2018-02-20T06:54:03.484267+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2018-02-20T06:54:03.484268+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2018-02-20T06:54:03.484270+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
2018-02-20T06:54:03.484271+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2018-02-20T06:54:03.484273+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
2018-02-20T06:54:03.484275+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2018-02-20T06:54:03.484277+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 352, in import_app
2018-02-20T06:54:03.484278+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2018-02-20T06:54:03.484338+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
2018-02-20T06:54:03.484677+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-02-20 06:54:03 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2018-02-20T06:54:03.590746+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-02-20 06:54:03 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2018-02-20T06:54:03.590997+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-02-20 06:54:03 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2018-02-20T06:54:03.801591+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2018-02-20T06:54:04.041064+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-02-20T06:54:04.029283+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2018-02-20T06:54:03.896607+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-02-20 06:54:03 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
2018-02-20T06:54:03.897225+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-02-20 06:54:03 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:13017 (4)
2018-02-20T06:54:03.897355+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-02-20 06:54:03 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2018-02-20T06:54:03.901981+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-02-20 06:54:03 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
2018-02-20T06:54:03.907379+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-02-20 06:54:03 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2018-02-20T06:54:03.907383+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-02-20T06:54:03.907385+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 578, in spawn_worker
2018-02-20T06:54:03.907387+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2018-02-20T06:54:03.907389+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
2018-02-20T06:54:03.907391+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.load_wsgi()
2018-02-20T06:54:03.907393+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 135, in load_wsgi
2018-02-20T06:54:03.907394+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2018-02-20T06:54:03.907396+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2018-02-20T06:54:03.907398+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2018-02-20T06:54:03.907400+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
2018-02-20T06:54:03.907402+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2018-02-20T06:54:03.907404+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
2018-02-20T06:54:03.907406+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2018-02-20T06:54:03.907408+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 352, in import_app
2018-02-20T06:54:03.907410+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2018-02-20T06:54:03.907417+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
2018-02-20T06:54:03.907561+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-02-20 06:54:03 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
2018-02-20T06:54:03.950849+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-02-20 06:54:03 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2018-02-20T06:54:03.950970+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-02-20 06:54:03 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2018-02-20T06:54:48.667089+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=the-wall-cricket.herokuapp.com request_id=ac09678c-ef2d-4f3a-9d96-f0c60232eef3 fwd="157.49.23.47" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-02-20T06:54:51.281797+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=the-wall-cricket.herokuapp.com request_id=c779ab65-1b04-443a-b17b-438cfe914a17 fwd="157.49.23.47" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-02-20T06:54:51.189245+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/robots.txt" host=the-wall-cricket.herokuapp.com request_id=6d88e51d-44c6-4389-aac5-c24595aad59c fwd="157.49.105.219" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-02-20T06:54:51.849753+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/robots.txt" host=the-wall-cricket.herokuapp.com request_id=501e291a-0426-477b-ab30-b9e2c00865fb fwd="157.49.23.47" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-02-20T06:54:52.823503+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/robots.txt" host=the-wall-cricket.herokuapp.com request_id=7173cf2e-806d-4675-8e9e-442624e55f1c fwd="157.49.23.47" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

what's wrong with this, How can I successfully deploy an app??

Comment: You have to define a procfile and tell which is the start file of the app. Here is an example of one of my procfiles: `web:gunicorn pub_main:app`. In your case it would be either `bbl:app` or `score:app`

Comment: in my case, start file is __init__.py it contains flask main file, can't I define __init__.py file ?

Comment: thanks, @roman finally it worked.

Comment: problem is I didn't define the Procfile properly and few pips are not installed.

Comment: if my main app is called app.py does it have to be in same directory as procfile? It worked on my previous app but not working now, can not figure out why.

Answer (score 17):

`web:gunicorn app:app` is standard Procfile. It expects that your .py file should be named app.py.

If you want to change .py name you should change Procfile as well.
`web:gunicorn my_app_name:app`
After that you can name your file - my_app_name.py

Answer (score 4):

On your local machine, at the base of your repository, you need to add a Procfile (exactly like this).

Inside that, paste only one line:
web: gunicorn :app

Example: If you want to trigger init.py, then:

```
web: gunicorn init:app
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case, this was resolved after I made the following changes, of course committing the changes before pushing to heroku:

1) ran `pip freeze > requirements.txt`,

2) moved my `app.py` to a different directory, and updated `Procfile`, `manage.py` -all files importing app.py- and to reflect the new location. I'm not sure if moving the file actually made a difference, it seems unlikely, but regardless, it's worth verifying all files that import `app` have the correct path