# Send a message using message.content

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to send a message which uses the message content
If a user writes `!alcool`, for example, I want my bot to answer `textealcool.png`

If they write `!car`, I want `textecar.png`.

My code is :

```
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

BOT_PREFIX = ("!")
TOKEN = "XXXXXX"

client = Bot(command_prefix=BOT_PREFIX)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("!"):
        newMessage = 'texte' + str(message.content)[1:] + '.png'
        await client.send_message(message.channel, newMessage)

client.run(TOKEN)
```

I wrote "!alcool" but my Bot answered with :

```
textealcool
texte!alcool
textealcool
texte
textealcool.pgn
textealcool.pgn
textealcool
textealcool.pgn
textealcool
```

I don't understand why I have so many answers with only two are right.

Comment: The reason you might be seeing more outputs is that you have multiple instances running at the same time on the same token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line
`newMessage = 'texte' + str(messagelu)[1:] + '.png'` what is `messagelu`?
Change `messagelu` to `message.content` and it will work

Comment: messagelu=message.content /

message.content was the code from the start but i tried to use reference after that. => it doesn't work with message.content :(

Comment: It should, are you sure you're not running the old code versions simultaneously?

Comment: It's possible. I don't really understand how the discord bot is linked to my program. thanks.

Comment: I am pretty sure now it's due to my bot running old version of my programm in the same time.
I tried to change my programm to send a link to a picture and only one echoes show the link to the picture.
Do you know how I can avoid that please ? Thanks.

Comment: I solved my problem by doing ctrl+alt+suppr and kill all python runing in windows 10.
But does it mean my bot won't do anything if I turn off my pc ?

Comment: Unless you host it somewhere like heroku when you shut down your pc it will turn off

Comment: I thank you a lot Tristo.
I create a gitHub and Heroku account but I am stuck with another problem (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord') but it's not the topic here.

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52247301/how-do-i-host-my-discord-py-bot-on-heroku/52254616#52254616) checklist I created a while back

Comment: It sounds like you need to update [your procfile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51914768/9917504)

Comment: I am working on it and I am stuck again.
I tried to add each of these items and nothing work :
discord.py==3.6.7 ||
git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py@rewrite#egg=discord.py[voice] ||
discord ||
discord.py

Comment: I don't know what the problem could be and the comment formatting is often very limited, try making a new post explaining the issue

Comment: The problem came from spelling requirement.txt instead of requirements.txt...doh !