# Django ModuleNotFoundError for urlpattern in Heroku deployment

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have a problem with my Django project after deploying it to Heroku. When I go to the project url on Heroku, I am hit with a "ModuleNotFoundError at / No module named 'spotify.urls' ". spotify is an app name in my project called bio_project. This error message leads me to believe that there is something wrong with my urls somehow or perhaps even settings.py

bio_project urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("", include("spotify.urls"))
]
```

spotify urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include 
from . import views
app_name = "spotify"
urlpatterns = [ 
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("authorize", views.authorize, name="authorize"),
    path("callback", views.callback, name="callback"),
    path("short_term", views.short_term, name="short_term"),
    path("medium_term", views.medium_term, name="medium_term"),
    path("long_term", views.long_term, name="long_term"),
]
```

Here is the error:

ModuleNotFoundError at /
No module named 'spotify.urls'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:
Django Version: 3.2.6
Exception Type: ModuleNotFoundError
Exception Value:
No module named 'spotify.urls'
Exception Location: , line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version: 3.9.5
Python Path:
['/app/.heroku/python/bin',
'/app',
'/app/.heroku/python/lib/python39.zip',
'/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9',
'/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
'/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages']

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9qul.png)

I cannot seem to make any sense of the error since the app is still working perfectly on localhost. Any thoughts?

Edit1: This is my folder arrangement [screenshot of folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DugQi.png)

Comment: please refer this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48881293/flask-and-heroku-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-app

Comment: Hi! My Procfile is as the following: web: gunicorn bio_project.wsgi --log-file - . I believe this is configured correctly unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Yes, python-3.9.5 is in my runtime.txt file.